# consulta para obtener registros donde la llave primaria no es llave foranea de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

El contexto de esto es:

Tengo 2 tablas, una que se llama `clientes`(donde esta toda la informacion de la persona: nombre, apellido, etc) y `miembros`(donde algunas personas que cumplan ciertos requerimientos pasan a ser miembros, es decir que su llave primaria pasa como llave foranea a la tabla miembros). Lo que deseo es obtener todos los clientes que no son miembros. Para ello se me ocurrio la siguiente consulta:

> SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `email`, `foto_perfil` FROM `clientes` WHERE 0 = SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM miembros WHERE `id_cliente` = SELECT `id` FROM clientes)

pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Análisis estático:
>
> Se encontraron 7 errores durante el análisis.
>
> 1. Este tipo de cláusula se analizó previamente. (near "SELECT" at position 84)
> 2. Se esperaba una expresión. (near "EXISTS" at position 91)
> 3. Palabra clave no reconocida. (near "EXISTS" at position 91)
> 4. Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "(" at position 97)
> 5. Este tipo de cláusula se analizó previamente. (near "SELECT" at position 98)
> 6. Este tipo de cláusula se analizó previamente. (near "SELECT" at position 142)
> 7. Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near ")" at position 167)
>
> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM miembros WHERE `id_cliente` = SELECT `id` FROM clien' en la linea 1

o talvez exista otra forma de hacerlo, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente NOT IN (
    SELECT id_cliente FROM miembros
  );
```

Por favor, envíame cualquier duda que te surja para documentar lo mejor posible la respuesta.

Comment: Para poder comprobar que funciona, por favor, modifica tu pregunta incluyendo un dataset para pruebas. Lo obtienes en phpMyAdmin/Exportar

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion, muchas gracias.

Comment: Genial, no olvides validar la respuesta (el tick bajo el voto)